# SQL statement ignored and missing opening parenthesis

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I get these errors during a creation of a trigger but I don't understand why

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER magazzino_bef_ins
BEFORE INSERT ON MAGAZZINO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
tempcodice varchar2(8);
cacc char(3);
ogg int;
CURSOR cursore_disp IS
        SELECT cacciatore, oggetto
        FROM TABLE EDDY.disponibilita
        WHERE ID_DISPONIBILITA = :NEW.disponibilità;
BEGIN
CURSOR cursore_disp IS
        SELECT cacciatore, oggetto
        FROM TABLE DISPONIBILITA
        WHERE ID_DISPONIBILITA = :NEW.disponibilità;
open cursore_disp;
fetch cursore_disp into cacc,ogg;
temp:= pk_gestione_magazzino.genera_catalogo(cacc,ogg);
:new.codcatalogo:=temp;
END;
```

The errors are:

> Error(5,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   Errore(6,20): PL/SQL: ORA-00906: missing opening parenthesis
>   Errore(9,8): PLS-00103: encountered symbol "CURSORE_DISP" instead of one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

I can't understand these errors, I'm just trying to take the values from a table in where the id inserted is equal in the other table.

Comment: replace ogg int with ogg PLS_INTEGER

Answer (score 0):

Here's how. I created test environment which is kind of *stupid*, but it makes the following code *work*.

```
SQL> create table magazzino (disponibilita number, codcatalogo varchar2(8));

Table created.

SQL> create table disponibilita (cacciatore char(3), oggetto number, id_disponibilita number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace package pk_gestione_magazzino as
  2    function genera_catalogo (cacc number, ogg number) return varchar2;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pk_Gestione_magazzino as
  2    function genera_catalogo (cacc number, ogg number) return varchar2 is
  3    begin
  4      return 'Little';
  5    end;
  6  end;
  7  /

Package body created.
```

---

Trigger which causes you trouble: no need for a cursor; moreover, you have two of them (was it just a typo)? It looks as if you used it to avoid *no data found* error. If so, don't do it - it just makes confusion. Handle exceptions properly. By the way, you "forgot" to close the cursor.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger magazzino_bef_ins
  2    before insert on magazzino
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    cacc       char(3);
  6    ogg        int;
  7  begin
  8    select cacciatore, oggetto
  9      into cacc, ogg
 10      from disponibilita
 11      where id_disponibilita = :new.disponibilita;
 12
 13    :new.codcatalogo := pk_gestione_magazzino.genera_catalogo (cacc, ogg);
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into disponibilita values (1, 1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into magazzino (disponibilita) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From magazzino;

DISPONIBILITA CODCATAL
------------- --------
            1 Little

SQL>
```

Works, kind of.